# SQL getting sum and all rows in one go

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the total sum of the column amount and all the rows at the same time.

```
SELECT sum(orders.amount) as total, orders.transactionID, orders.itemid, products.id, 
products.category, products.price 
FROM db.orders 
INNER JOIN db.products 
ON orders.itemid = products.id 
WHERE transactionID = '012906ea51c14b0881c4785527c606dd'
```

The query above only gives me the total value and only one row (I also want to have all the rows)

```
SELECT sum(orders.amount) as total, orders.transactionID, orders.itemid, products.id, 
products.category, products.price 
FROM db.orders 
INNER JOIN db.products 
ON orders.itemid = products.id 
WHERE transactionID = '012906ea51c14b0881c4785527c606dd'
GROUP BY orders.id
```

While the second query gives me every row but incorrect total of `orders.amount`

Can this be done?

(I made the two queries a little shorter)

Thanks

Comment: "incorrect" in what way?

Comment: it seems I only get the sum of 1 row instead of all the rows

Comment: that's because you grouped it by the order ID. You can either get an aggregate of the rows (e.g. the Sum) as a single output, or you can get a dump of all the row data. You can't get both in one query, that's just not how SQL works. If you want to know both things you need two separate queries. Or, you just dump out the data, and do the "sum" part of it offline in some other tool such as Excel.

Comment: Query 1.. SUM without GROUP BY always generates 1 row.  Query 2 is a invalid use off GROUP BY read (https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've shamelessly copied your comment to include it in my answer :) Hope you're okay with it.

Comment: Don't mind atleast you give me the credits @fancyPants

Comment: @RaymondNijland Of course I did.

Comment: @RaymondNijland bedankt voor het verwijzen en de uitleg!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a "running total", meaning, using a variable and summarize the values yourself. The correct sum will appear in the last row of your result set.

```
SELECT @my_sum := @my_sum + orders.amount as running_total, 
orders.transactionID, 
orders.itemid, 
products.id, 
products.category, 
products.price 
FROM db.orders 
INNER JOIN db.products 
ON orders.itemid = products.id 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @my_sum:=0) AS var_init_subquery
WHERE transactionID = '012906ea51c14b0881c4785527c606dd'
```

- read more about user variables [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

Also have a look at Raymond Nijland's comment:

> Query 1.. SUM without GROUP BY always generates 1 row. Query 2 is a invalid use off GROUP BY read https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Awesome! Will read the article you mentioned, thanks for the explanation and solution to my problem :)